# Remove an XML node if an attribute of a child element matches a given value

Tags: xslt

I am a new bie in xslt and I have a requirement to remove an entire node from an xml file, if one of the child element attribute value matches a particular string.
Input xml file is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <gpm xmlns="http://www.airbus.com/topcased/gPM" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.airbus.com/topcased/gPM">
    <version>1.2</version>
        <version>1.2</version>
<filters>
  <sheetFilter description=" " labelKey="Liste de distribution" hidden="false">
    <userLogin>TO44452</userLogin>
    <resultSummary>
      <fieldResult name="DL_NAME"/>
      <fieldResult name="DL_USERS"/>
      <fieldResult name="$SHEET_STATE"/>
    </resultSummary>
    <scope>
      <productScope name="$CURRENT_PRODUCT" includeSubProducts="false"/>
    </scope>
    <containers>
      <sheetTypeRef name="DistributionList"/>
    </containers>
  </sheetFilter>
  <sheetFilter .../>
          ....
        </filters>
    </gpm>
```

I have to remove the entire  node if name attribute of  element matches a particular value.

The xslt file I have used is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.airbus.com/topcased/gPM"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:gpmns="http://www.airbus.com/topcased/gPM"
    exclude-result-prefixes="gpmns">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <!-- Delete extra blank lines -->
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- template for any attribute node, copy  -->
    <xsl:template match="*|@*" name="copy_all">
        <xsl:copy disable-output-escaping="yes">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="gpmns:sheetTypeRef[@name = 'DL']">
        <xsl:apply-templates match="gpmns:sheetFilter"/>
        </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The transformation what I got is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpm xmlns="http://www.airbus.com/topcased/gPM" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.airbus.com/topcased/gPM">
<version>1.2</version>
<filters>
<sheetFilter description=" " labelKey="Liste de distribution" hidden="false">
<userLogin>TO44452</userLogin>
<resultSummary>
<fieldResult name="DL_NAME"/>
<fieldResult name="DL_USERS"/>
<fieldResult name="$SHEET_STATE"/>
</resultSummary>
<scope>
<productScope name="$CURRENT_PRODUCT" includeSubProducts="false"/>
</scope>
<containers/>
</sheetFilter>
<sheetFilter ..... />
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Sorry, but what you mean saying 'remove'? Do you want to apply some template to `filters/sheetFilter` and skip some `sheetFilter` nodes, or anything else?

Comment: Yes I want to skip some sheetFilter nodes if name attribute of element <sheetTypeRef> matches a particular value.

Comment: Well, in this case you can try to use the code I posted in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two possibilities to manage that:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="filters/sheetFilter"/>

<xsl:template match="filters/sheetFilter[containers/sheetTypeRef/@name != 'DL']">
    … your output goes here …
</xsl:template>
```

or

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="filters/sheetFilter[containers/sheetTypeRef/@name != 'DL']"/>

<xsl:template match="filters/sheetFilter">
    … your output goes here …
</xsl:template>
```

depending on your purpose.

Comment: Actually the below code is working for me **{<xsl:template match="gpmns:sheetTypeRef[@name = 'DistributionList']">
  <xsl:apply-templates match="gpmns:sheetFilter"/>
     </xsl:template> }**   (don't mind gpmns:)   but only the <containers> element is removed. Any clues ?

Comment: Could you please update your question and provide the code you use and transformations you get. That will definitely help to understand your problem better.

Comment: As I see in your XSL template, you use improper contexts: you try to match `sheetFilter` within `sheetTypeRef`, which is not correct, since `sheetTypeRef` is a child of `sheetFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to find a solution as below:
may be it'll be usefull to some one.

```
<xsl:template match="sheetFilter[*/sheetTypeRef[@name='DistributionList']]"/>
```

Thanks Rodion for your suggestion.

Susan